# How can i auto translate titles from any language to english?

Tags: language

I am working on created a simple image bookmarking site with wordpress, currently it has a bookmarklet that allows user to collect images from other domains with one click.

This bookmarklet auto-fetches title from the source site and the problem with this process is that many other sites that user might collect images from, are gonna be non-english ones. so the bookmarklet will fetch that non english title and make a post with it.

Is there an easy solution to solve this? maybe by adding some function on function.php file that auto translates the non-english title to english by using google api maybe? If yes can you please give me the function code that can do this?

Thanks for Reading :) 
and sorry for the Bad english :P
I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make any text to be translated you have to use a plugin and mark the text as translatable. To do so you have to use `__()` or `_e()` instead of `echo`. The difference beetwen `__()` and `_e()` is that first one doesn't `echo` the text while second one does. So if you do something like this: `__("Some text", "text domain")` it will be marked as translatable text but it won't be displayed but if you use `_e("Some text","text domain")` the text will be also displayed on screen. Now if anyone will install a plugin he will see translated text

Comment: I don't think he is searching something like this - he wants it to be AUTO translated with some kind of external Translator.

Answer (score 0):

actually it's really easy - with [Google Translator API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/)

1. Get an API Key from Google.
2. Write yourself a function (to the functions.php) to translate text.
3. Profit.

Here is how to start and where you get the API Key etc.: https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/quickstart